# Retrieving a foreign key value in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework to create a REST Api. My serializers:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): #inherit from this class
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.id')

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('id','name', 'owner')


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Item.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'items')
```

The only model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now if I `GET` the users:

> HTTP 200 OK
>   Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
>   Content-Type: application/json
>   Vary: Accept
>   [
>       {
>           "id": 1,
>           "username": "chuck",
>           "items": [
>               1,
>               2
>           ]
>       }
>   ]

I receive all the items that this user has (by the way I could I get the name instead of the primary keys of the items ?).

How would I go if I wanted to reverse that process and get all the owners of the objects ? Here's the response I have so far (the owners are missing) :

> HTTP 200 OK
>   Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
>   Content-Type: application/json
>   Vary: Accept
>   [
>       {
>           "id": 1,
>           "name": "Vest"
>       },
>       {
>           "id": 2,
>           "name": "Pants"
>       }
>   ]`

I have tried to add `owners = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner')` as you can see in the code (commented parts), but I have the following error :

`Object of type 'User' is not JSON serializable`

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You are almost there.
In your ItemSerializer, Try

```
serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.id')
```

or

```
owner = UserSerializer()
```

If you want to see all user information

Answer (score 3):

If you want to receive name of the item instead of primary key, you could just change `items` to `StringRelatedField` and then `__str__` from your `Item` will be used.

```
items = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
```

But even better solution would be [Nested relationship](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships). You simply change `items` to serializer defining items, eg:

```
items = ItemSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
```

Another solution would be that you remove `owner` and define depth. This way all information about owners (users) will be serialized:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        depth = 1
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'owner')
```

and for `items`

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        depth = 1
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'items')
```

Now for the reverse, list of items with owners, it's not possible with `ModelSerializer`. You probably have to manually do that. Here is an example, where you don't need a serializer.

```
class ItemOwnerViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

    def list(self, request):
        data = []
        queryset = Item.objects.values('name', 'owner__username')
        for item in queryset:
            temp = dict()
            t = next((i for i in data if i['name'] == item['name']), None)
            if t:
                t['owners'].append(item['owner__username'])
            else:
                temp['name'] = item['name']
                temp['owners'] = [item['owner__username']]
                data.append(temp)

        return Response(data)
```

Serializer for this `viewset` would probably be something along these lines:

```
class ItemOwnerSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    name = serializers.CharField()
    owners = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField())
```

I haven't tested all this, but I guess it should work. I hope it helps.